# .net 6-WinForms-DataBound UserControl containing ComboBox - Why is it so hard to set the ComboBox bindings

Tags: .net, winforms, data-binding, user-controls, lookup-tables

I am using WinForms, c#, .net 6 and VS2022Preview
What I am trying to achieve is to create a WinForm UserControl that contains a ComboBox and support Lookup Data Binding

        
   
I have followed the steps described in this article.

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/create-a-windows-forms-user-control-that-supports-lookup-data-binding?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp

It seems that it only works for .Net Framework and not for .Net!! or at least I can not find where and how to declare  the DisplayMember, the ValueMember, the DataSource and the LookupMember

Guys, am I missing something? Why is it so hard to DataBind a UserControl to LookupTables?
Thanx for your time and look forward to seeing your advise or some article that could possibly help me...

Comment: Hi. I'm sorry, but I don't fully understand the problem. Could you rewrite it, and if possible, share a minimal codebase that exhibits the behavior so we can test on our side?

Answer (score -1):

As You Said, It only works for .NET Framework and not for .NET.

Microsoft has yet not implemented Data Binding feature in .NET Core or .NET.

Here is the link for Official Microsoft Forum Discussion:- "https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/unable-to-add-a-new-data-source-to-my-windows-form/1318286"

The Only Solution for your problem is to Shift to .NET Framework 4.8.0 (Long Term Support Version).

Hope this response satisfies your question.

Happy Coding !!